# py2app Mac OS deployment build

Tags: python, macos, deployment, py2app

I am able to compile a python script into a mac OS application using py2app, however it only runs on os 10.12 (which is what I am running).
From what I gather, this has something to do with the deployment build (MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) selected. I know this is an option in Xcode, but after hours of searching I can't seem to figure out how to change this when compiling using py2app. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Tweaking your Info.plist](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/tweaking.html).You need to specify what platforms the application will run on otherwise it will default to the runtime libraries for current OSX release.

> You do need to take care w.r.t. C extensions, those might pick up
>   dependencies on the current OS while building (in my experience that's
>   mostly a problem with some C libraries with a configure script that
>   detect C functions to use). The easiest way to avoid those problems is
>   to build wheels for C extensions on 10.10 then install those on the
>   Sierra machine.

Also you can see this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/210/how-to-create-apps-for-multiple-osx).Hope this helps.